# Open/View Android External SD files and folders

Tags: android

I am running below lines of code to Open Picture Gallery in Android Programmatically,It working fine .

```
final static int RQS_GET_IMAGE = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_GET_IMAGE);
```

In my application sometimes I need to open the external SD card Root Directory to select random file desired by user.
Anyone can guide how can I open (open and explore) the external card files and folders from my application?

Thanks in advance for help .

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set user-permission to write access to SD card in Android Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Without it you can't access to SD card. Next you should work with SD Card like HDD on PC

Hope, it's help you.

Comment: Dear ihrupin thanks  .I already done this,My problem related to how I can open/view the SD card directories . . Thanks Again

Comment: I add the permssion that is fine but problem is about how I can directly open the External SD card root directory View when I click on button to select a file. . ?